# JodaTime de/serialization across time zones breaks code

Tags: serialization, deserialization, jodatime

After deploying to production environemnt my code broke, and after quite a bit of bug chasing, I discovered that JodaTime was handling de/serialization differently in production than in dev environement. Apparently significantly, the production server is on another time zone.

Deserialization and serialization on development:

```
scala> val input = "2013-09-07T17:11:03.117+03:00"
input: String = 2013-09-07T17:11:03.117+03:00

scala> val thisIsDev = new DateTime(input).toString()
thisIsDev: String = 2013-09-07T17:11:03.117+03:00

scala> input == thisIsDev
res3: Boolean = true
```

Notice the `+03:00` at the end of the ISO8601 string, both initially and after reserialization. Now this is what happens in production, which is on +0 time zone:

```
scala> val sameInput = "2013-09-07T17:11:03.117+03:00"
sameInput: String = 2013-09-07T17:11:03.117+03:00

scala> val thisIsProd = new DateTime(sameInput).toString()
thisIsProd: String = 2013-09-07T14:11:03.117Z

scala> sameInput == thisIsProduction
res1: Boolean = false
```

As you can see, `+03:00` was absolved and the date string's format changed time zones.

Is this a solved problem? Suggestions?

**Edit:**

To clarify, the problem with this is that if I serialize, change time zones (go to a different server for example), then deserialize and reserialize, I end up with a different string than what I started with. This is why my production broke, but my tests didn't. Took me a while to figure this out.

Note: These ISO8601 strings are used on a CouchDb server that sorts them alphanumerically, that's why I can't use JodaTime methods for comparison.

**Edit 2:**

Ideally the answer would suggest how to deserialize an ISO8601 string into DateTime object without loosing the time zone information (on different time zones).

**Edit 2.1:** [I opened a relevant question and got the solution I needed here.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18946311/1714997)

Comment: There isn't enough information here to understand what the actual problem is.  The two times are both equivalent, as can be seen if you try `new DateTime("2013-09-07T17:11:03.117+03:00").equals(new DateTime("2013-09-07T14:11:03.117Z"))`.  Please show the full error information and the code which is causing it.

Comment: @jgm, in response I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your edited question, the simplest answer is to force every datetime to be in the same timezone, so for example

```
scala> new DateTime("2013-09-07T17:11:03.117+03:00").withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC)
res1: org.joda.time.DateTime = 2013-09-07T14:11:03.117Z

scala> new DateTime("2013-09-07T14:11:03.117Z").withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC)
res2: org.joda.time.DateTime = 2013-09-07T14:11:03.117Z
```

However be aware that in this situation you are losing information i.e. the timezone in which the date resides.  If you are using your date for internal purposes (e.g. finding new items) then this doesn't matter so much, bit if you are sending your data back to users then you need to find another solution.