# ISO8601 to DateTime with time zone information preserved

Tags: java, datetime, deserialization, jodatime

Below is a deserialization of an ISO8601 date string that contains time zone information. Notice that the time zone information is lost:

```
scala> val date1 = new DateTime().withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Berlin"))
date1: org.joda.time.DateTime = 2013-09-22T18:42:15.348+02:00

scala> date1.getZone()
res45: org.joda.time.DateTimeZone = Europe/Berlin

scala> val date2 = new DateTime(date1.toString())
date2: org.joda.time.DateTime = 2013-09-22T19:42:15.348+03:00

scala> date2.getZone()
res46: org.joda.time.DateTimeZone = Europe/Vilnius

scala> date1.getZone() == date2.getZone()
res47: Boolean = false
```

Time zone information (UTC offset) is serialized, as in `+03:00` and `+02:00` at the end of the ISO8601 strings, but it is lost after deserialization. As you can see the `date2` DateTime object, which I expected to be a copy of `date1` has the system's UTC offset instead of `+02:00`, which `date1` had.

How do I deserialize an ISO8601 string as to preserve the UTC offset?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The constructor you are using, [`new DateTime(Object instant)`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime%28java.lang.Object%29), (actually passed through to `BaseDateTime`) doesn't *parse*, instead it *converts* the given object (in your case, a `String`).

Long story short, it uses the default time zone:

1. The constructor considers the passed parameter an `Instant` and requests an [InstantConverter](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/convert/InstantConverter.html) from [`ConverterManager`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/convert/ConverterManager.html)
2. The constructor calls [`getInstantMillis()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/joda-time/joda-time/2.0/org/joda/time/convert/StringConverter.java#StringConverter.getInstantMillis%28java.lang.Object%2Corg.joda.time.Chronology%29) on that `StringConverter`
3. That method actually does use a standard ISO 8601 `DateTimeFormatter`, however instead of `parse` [it calls `parseMillis()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/joda-time/joda-time/2.0/org/joda/time/convert/StringConverter.java#StringConverter.getInstantMillis%28java.lang.Object%2Corg.joda.time.Chronology%29).
4. `parseMillis`, as you can see from the [javadocs](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parseMillis%28java.lang.String%29), returns a date in the **default time zone**.

Use `DateTime.parse` instead:

```
DateTime date2 = DateTime.parse(date1.toString());
// 2013-09-22T19:21:48.461+02:00
```

Comment: Brilliant! I had already found a way using `ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser().withOffsetParsed().parseDateTime(dateTimeString)`, but this is much nicer on the eyes. Cheers.

Comment: @DominykasMostauskis Great!  I spent the last 20 minutes parsing the code and updated my answer with an explanation.  It's always good to know *why* it works that way.  Hope this helps.  Don't forget to upvote if it helped :)